# T-SQL Max date and min date with value single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First of all I would like to thank the friends who helped this complex and difficult query.

I have three tables

Table 1

```
 StaffId     FirstName       LastName   staffType
---------------------------------------
   1          Adam            Sorme      Student 
   2          Lara            Sandra     Teacher
   3          Jack            Jones      Student
```

Table 2

```
 GateId   GateName  
 ---------------------------------------
   1        frontDoor
   2        superDoor
```

Table 3

```
Id transitionDate     GateId  StaffId 
 ---------------------------------------
1  2018-01-1 08:00:00    1     1
2  2018-01-1 10:00:00    2     1
3  2018-01-1 20:00:00    2     1
4  2018-01-2 07:00:00    1     2
5  2018-01-2 10:00:00    1     3
6  2018-01-9 12:00:00    2     2
```

I want the first and last movements of students **for each day**. Value must be set to null if no movement is available between the specified dates

```
transitionDate> '2018-01-1 00:00:00 000' 
 and transitionDate< '2018-01-03 00:00:00 000'
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Id     Date    MinTransitionDate    MaxTransitionDate    FirstGateName LastGateName    StaffId    StaffType
  1   2018-01-01  2018-01-1 08:00:00 2018-01-1 20:00:00    frontDoor      superDoor         1         Student
  2   2018-01-01  null                null                  null           null             3         student
  3   2018-01-02  null                null                  null           null             1         student
  4   2018-01-02  2018-01-2 10:00:00  null                 frontDoor       null             3         student
```

Comment: Can you include what you have tried, and any issues you are having

Comment: also include your ddls and insert scripts.

Comment: is that Front door is for entry (First movement)and Backdoor is for Exit (Last movement)..?

Comment: @MatthewEvans I do not get the result I want.

Comment: @Mahesh.K no rule. it can be a different gate name

Comment: @RadimBača every day to see who did not come There are 2 people in the student type. date range valid for 2 days

Comment: @PawanKumar there is no script. can you help me?

Comment: @RadimBača this is my record. As an example, I added records outside the date range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try a query like below

<kbd>**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/LEXZA10134)**</kbd>

```
create table staff(StaffId int,   FirstName  nvarchar(10),  LastName nvarchar(10),  staffType nvarchar(10))
insert into staff values
(1,'Adam','Sorme','Student') 
,(2,'Lara','Sandra','Teacher')
,(3,'Jack','Jones','Student')

go

create table gate(GateId int,  GateName  nvarchar(10))
insert into gate values
(1,'frontDoor')
,(2,'superDoor')

go
create table logs 
(Id int, transitionDate  datetime,   GateId  int, StaffId  int)
insert into logs values
(1,'2018-01-1 08:00:00',1,1)
,(2,'2018-01-1 10:00:00',2,1)
,(3,'2018-01-1 20:00:00',2,1)
,(4,'2018-01-2 07:00:00',1,2)
,(5,'2018-01-2 10:00:00',1,3)
,(6,'2018-01-9 12:00:00',2,2)
go
declare @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime
select @startdate='2018-01-1 00:00:00' , @enddate='2018-01-03 00:00:00'


; with tempSet as 
(
    select 
    transitionDatetime=l.transitionDate,
    gateName=g.gateName,
    staffid=l.staffid,
    idx=
         row_number() over(partition by l.staffid order by l.transitionDate ) -
        row_number() over(partition by l.staffid,cast(l.transitionDate as date) order by l.transitionDate ),
    transitionDate=cast(l.transitionDate as date)
    from
    logs l inner join staff s on
    l.staffid=s.staffid and staffType='Student'
    join gate g on g.gateid=l.gateid
)
, groupedSet as
(
    select 
    t1.*,
    FirstGateName=t2.gatename,
    lastGateName=t3.gatename
    from
    (
        select
        staffid,
        mintransitionDate=min(transitionDatetime),
        maxtransitionDate= case when count(1)>1 then max(transitionDatetime) else null end,
        transitionDate=max(transitionDate),
        idx
        from
        tempSet 
        group by staffid,idx
    ) t1
    left join
    tempSet t2
    on t1.idx=t2.idx 
    and t1.staffid=t2.staffid and t1.mintransitionDate=t2.transitionDatetime
     left join
    tempSet t3
    on t1.idx=t3.idx 
    and t1.staffid=t3.staffid and t1.maxtransitionDate=t3.transitionDatetime
    where t1.transitionDate between @startdate and @enddate
 )

 select
 t.*,
 g.mintransitionDate,
 g.maxtransitionDate,
 g.FirstGateName,
 g.LastGateName
 from 
 groupedSet g
 right join
 (
     select 
         d,
         staffid
     from
     (
         select 
         top  (select datediff(d,@startdate, @endDate))
         d=dateadd(d,row_number() over(order by (select null))-1, @startDate)
         from
         sys.objects o1 cross join sys.objects o2
     )tally
          cross join
     staff 
     where staff.stafftype='Student'
    )t
 on cast(t.d as date)=cast(g.transitionDate as date) and t.staffid=g.staffid
 order by t.d asc, t.staffid asc
```

Comment: can u help me Dhruv

Comment: sure I can... let me check

Comment: @serenity but you have marked a response as correct answer... what help do you need?

Comment: why do write this part (  select 
         top  (select datediff(d,@startdate, @endDate))
         d=dateadd(d,row_number() over(order by (select null))-1, @startDate)
         from
         sys.objects o1 cross join sys.objects o2
     )tally ))))

Comment: @serenity that's called a tally or numbers table.

Comment: @serenity www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Comment: Explanation: table sys.object is always in memory so it is not read unlike the other tables. Last part `from sys.objects o1 cross join sys.objects o2 ` is actually a cross join between same two tables which should produce sufficient high number of resultant rows

Comment: I really congratulate you on this one. Is the performance of this question good? I will run on too many records.

Comment: Explanation: statement `select top N * from tableT` can also be written as `select top (select N) * from tableT`, allowing us to parametrize the N part. Here I'v calculated N as difference of days between start and end and added one so that I can get exact number of days needed for series.

Comment: @serenity Yes. Tally table work in memory don't ready anything from I/O so are fast

Comment: http://rextester.com/live/FTYV76344 Finally, when you compare yourself with that query, which one is performance. Which should I choose?

Comment: can u check it ?

Answer (score 1):

All insert statements:

```
create table #Staff (StaffId int, FirstName varchar(20), LastName varchar(20), staffType varchar(20))
insert into #Staff values
(1, 'Adam', 'Sorme', 'Student'), 
(2, 'Lara', 'Sandra', 'Teacher'),
(3, 'Jack', 'Jones', 'Student')

create table #Gates (GateId int, GateName varchar(20)) 
insert into #Gates values
(1, 'frontDoor'),
(2, 'backDoor')

create table #Transitions (Id int, transitionDate datetime, GateId int, StaffId  int)
insert into #Transitions values
(1, '2018-01-1 08:00:00', 1, 1),
(2, '2018-01-1 10:00:00', 2, 1),
(3, '2018-01-1 20:00:00', 2, 1),
(4, '2018-01-2 07:00:00', 1, 2),
(5, '2018-01-2 10:00:00', 1, 3),
(6, '2018-01-9 12:00:00', 2, 2)
```

In order to get desired result, you'll need CTE with all days between range. Limits (dates) of range you specify in variables included in below query.

```
declare @maxTransitionDate datetime, @minTransitionDate datetime
select @maxTransitionDate='2018-01-10', @minTransitionDate='2018-01-01'
;with cte as (
    select @minTransitionDate [Days]
    union all
    select dateadd(day,1,[Days]) from cte where [Days] < @maxTransitionDate
)
,cte2 as (
    select [Days], [StaffId], [FirstName], [LastName] from cte cross apply #staff where stafftype ='Student'
)

select C.[Days] [Date], C.[staffid], C.FirstName, C.LastName, A.mintransitiondate, A.[maxtransitiondate], A.firstgatename, A.lastgatename, A.staffType from (
    select T.[Date],
           T.staffid,
           T.mintransitiondate,
           case when T.maxtransitiondate <> T.mintransitiondate then T.maxtransitiondate end [maxtransitiondate],
           (select gatename from #gates where gateid = T.firstgateid) firstgatename,
           (select gatename from #gates where gateid = T.lastgateid) lastgatename,
           S.FirstName,
           S.LastName,
           S.staffType
    from (
        select [date], staffid,
               max(case when rn = 1 then transitiondate end) mintransitiondate,
               max(case when rn = cnt then transitiondate end) maxtransitiondate,
               max(case when rn = 1 then GateId end) FirstGateId,
               max(case when rn = cnt then GateId end) LastGateId
        from (
            select *, cast(transitiondate as date) [Date],
                   row_number() over (partition by staffid, cast(transitiondate as date) order by transitiondate) [rn],
                   count(*) over (partition by staffid, cast(transitiondate as date)) [cnt]
            from #Transitions
        ) a group by staffid, [date]
    ) [T] join #Staff [S] on T.staffid = S.staffid
    where S.staffType = 'Student'
) [A] right join cte2 [C] on A.[Date] = C.[Days] and A.[staffid] = C.[staffid]
```

Comment: http://rextester.com/UYUJJ14553 This is not what I want. Would you check the link

Comment: @serenity It's perfetcly accordant to your logic and data given. You desired output is wrong or you described the logic wrongly. But, tell me what's wrong according to you?

Comment: I want non-registered for every day to be null. Would you check the link http://rextester.com/LEXZA10134

Comment: I have given you the CTE, it's enough to `left join` it. That's all.

Comment: @serenity I updated query. It will list all transitions within given range in desired structure.

Comment: thank u its working. lastly I want to write students as staff in all of the students and write staff firstname and lastname inde. Would you change it like this?

Comment: @serenity You are welcome. First of all, if answer solves your problem, you should accept it. Secondly, to get answer to further requirements, ask another question, as this already became too broad.

Comment: I can not score because my score is low. The same problem concerns 2 areas. If you check 1 rejoice in the previous responsibility.

Comment: I added the score. Would you also add Firstname, lastname, and staffType. As output

Comment: can u help me ?

Comment: @serenity I added first and last names in the result :)

Comment: Dude, you asked me to open up a new question. I open it and answer it to you :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770508/how-do-i-insert-left-joins-in-a-nested-query

Comment: @serenity Ok, if my answer is enough (I thought that your requirements will continue), I will mark it as duplicate, since it has been already answered :)

Comment: dude I have a final case, firstname, lastname and staffType should not be null depending on the condition of the student. Thank you very much for this to solve this problem completely for me if you fix it. not finished yet :)

Comment: @serenity Updated query.

Comment: @serenity Nothing's wrong. You just changed `@maxTransitionDate` and `@minTransitionDate`. Everything is correct.

Comment: if you check the 4th record. Although maxtransitiondate is null, lastgatename is full, it has to be empty. Also, since I have taken all the records according to the student condition, all of the staffType must be students  http://rextester.com/live/FTYV76344

Comment: @serenity [Here's my last attempt](http://www.rextester.com/live/FTYV76344). Don't know what more I can do...

Comment: Thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem so complicated.

First, use `cross join` to get all the rows.  Then use `left join` and aggregation to get the information you want.

The basic query looks like this:

```
select s.staffId, d.dte,
       min(t.transitionDate) as first_change,
       max(t.transitionDate) as first_change,
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then gateId end) as first_gateid,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then gateId end) as last_gateid
from (select s.* from Staff s where stafftype = 'Student') s cross join
     (select distinct cast(transitionDate as date) as dte from Transitions) d left join
     (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by StaffId, cast(transitionDate as date) order by transitionDate) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by StaffId, cast(transitionDate as date) order by transitionDate desc) as seqnum_desc
      from Transitions t
     ) t
     on cast(t.transitiondate as date) = d.dte and
        t.staffId = s.staffId and
        1 in (t.seqnum_asc, t.seqnum_desc)
group by s.staffId, d.dte;
```

You can enhance the `select` to bring back more columns.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fffdb/1) is a SQL Fiddle.