# How do I insert left joins in a nested query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First of all I would like to thank the friends who helped this complex and difficult query.

I have three tables

Table 1

```
 StaffId     FirstName       LastName   staffType
---------------------------------------
   1          Adam            Sorme      Student 
   2          Lara            Sandra     Teacher
   3          Jack            Jones      Student
```

Table 2

```
 GateId   GateName  
 ---------------------------------------
   1        frontDoor
   2        superDoor
```

Table 3

```
Id transitionDate     GateId  StaffId 
 ---------------------------------------
1  2018-01-1 08:00:00    1     1
2  2018-01-1 10:00:00    2     1
3  2018-01-1 20:00:00    2     1
4  2018-01-2 07:00:00    1     2
5  2018-01-2 10:00:00    1     3
6  2018-01-9 12:00:00    2     2
```

I want the first and last movements of students **for each day**. Value must be set to null if no movement is available between the specified dates

```
transitionDate> '2018-01-1 00:00:00 000' 
 and transitionDate< '2018-01-03 00:00:00 000'
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Id     Date    MinTransitionDate    MaxTransitionDate    FirstGateName LastGateName    StaffId    StaffType
  1   2018-01-01  2018-01-1 08:00:00 2018-01-1 20:00:00    frontDoor      superDoor         1         Student
  2   2018-01-01  null                null                  null           null             3         student
  3   2018-01-02  null                null                  null           null             1         student
  4   2018-01-02  2018-01-2 10:00:00  null                 frontDoor       null             3         student
```

**The following query is partially working.**

```
select s.staffId, d.dte,
       min(t.transitionDate) as first_change,
       max(t.transitionDate) as first_change,
       max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then gateId end) as first_gateid,
       max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then gateId end) as last_gateid
from (select s.* from Staff s where stafftype = 'Student') s cross join
     (select distinct cast(transitionDate as date) as dte from Transitions) d left join
     (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by StaffId, cast(transitionDate as date) order by transitionDate) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by StaffId, cast(transitionDate as date) order by transitionDate desc) as seqnum_desc
      from Transitions t
     ) t
     on cast(t.transitiondate as date) = d.dte and
        t.staffId = s.staffId and
        1 in (t.seqnum_asc, t.seqnum_desc)
group by s.staffId, d.dte;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fffdb/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

**How do I add firstGateName and LastGateName to this query result?**

Comment: whats wrong with query, please add data and query here

Comment: A link to sqlfiddle is great, but it's not enough. You should also paste the relevant details into the question.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I fixed it. do you correct my score

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but I've upvoted it now to counter the downvote.

Comment: @BHouse I added. did you check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL Max date and min date with value single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762083/t-sql-max-date-and-min-date-with-value-single-row) Because my answer covered this question as well.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn can u check it http://rextester.com/live/WTXF69745 what is the mistake there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just join your existing query to the `Gates` table to get those names, i.e.

```
<existing query>
inner join Gates g1 on g1.gateId = (required gate id)
```

In your case you can join using the aggregate value you've

```
select 
    q.*, 
    g1.GateName as first_gate_name,
    g2.GateName as last_gate_name
from 
-- use existing query as a subquery, so we can easily use the first/last_gateid values
(
    select s.staffId, d.dte,
           min(t.transitionDate) as first_change,
           max(t.transitionDate) as last_change,
           max(case when seqnum_asc = 1 then gateId end) as first_gateid,
           max(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then gateId end) as last_gateid   
    from (select s.* from Staff s where stafftype = 'Student') s cross join
         (select distinct cast(transitionDate as date) as dte from Transitions) d left join
         (select t.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by StaffId, cast(transitionDate as date) order by transitionDate) as seqnum_asc,
                 row_number() over (partition by StaffId, cast(transitionDate as date) order by transitionDate desc) as seqnum_desc
          from Transitions t
         ) t
         on cast(t.transitiondate as date) = d.dte and
            t.staffId = s.staffId and
            1 in (t.seqnum_asc, t.seqnum_desc)
    group by s.staffId, d.dte
) q
-- join on the appropriate gate ids      
inner join Gates g1 on g1.gateId = q.first_gateid
inner join Gates g2 on g2.gateId = q.last_gateid
```

Comment: I fixed some minor syntax problems.

Comment: If the inner join is not left join corrected, the problem is solved. thank you.